# Take the subset of the file related to the time stamp

Tags: text-processing, awk, json

I have some json file in dictionary format. The lines looks like here:

```
{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "time":1334572551435}
{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"4", "time":1334575352456}
{"a":"2", "b":"2", "c":"7", "time":1334575335345}
...
```

time is in a UTC format. The whole file has about 300 milliones unique lines (anyway the same time could come twice). How I can choose a lines for some particular time, for example between `1334575352456` and `1334575353456`?

I personally have the next idea from some tutorial:

```
awk ’$"time" == 1334575352456, $"time" == 1334575353456’ inputfile.json
```

anyway, I suppose this solution is for column `"time"`, not for dictionary with the key `"time"` (Actually `$"time"` should be `$4`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'[:}]' '$(NF-1) >= 1334575352456 && $(NF-1) <= 1334575353456' file
{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"4", "time":1334575352456}
```

`-F'[:}]'` set fields delimiter is `:` or `}`, so you can access the the time value by accessing second from last field, using `$(NF-1)`.

To save ouput, use:

```
$ awk -F'[:}]' '$(NF-1) >= 1334575352456 && $(NF-1) <= 1334575353456' file > output.txt
```

If you have `gawk 4.1.0` and above, you can use `-i` option to make edit inplace:

```
$ awk -i inplace -F'[:}]' '$(NF-1) >= 1334575352456 && $(NF-1) <= 1334575353456' file
```

Comment: Yes, it works, many thanks. To save the output, I just should add the path and the file name at the end?

Comment: @Guforu: See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you, how I can improve $(NF-1) operation, if the time values is not in the last column, but for example in the 7th column from 12?

Comment: @Guforu: It depends on your input. But you can easily select `$7`...`$12`.

Comment: thank you very much, for me wasn't clear, that I can select dictionary by column.

Comment: @Guforu: No, you shouldn't think about dictionary in this case. `awk` only saw each line of your input as normal text, split it into number of fields, starting from `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input is a set of JSON objects, it makes sense to use a JSON-aware tool.

Using the `jq` JSON processor to extract only the entries that have a `time` value strictly between some `t0` and `t1` time values (the `-c` option used here selects "compact" output):

```bash
jq -c --argjson t0 1334572551435 --argjson t1 1334575352456 \
    'select(.time > $t0 and .time < $t1)' file
```

The equivalent command with Miller (`mlr`), albeit without parametrising the start and end of the time range:

```bash
mlr --json filter '$time > 1334572551435 && $time < 1334575352456' file
```